# Labelling Subplots (a) (b) (c) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How do I label the subplots at their bottom by their listing order like (a), (b), (c) in MATLAB? I am looking for a function that does this job.

Comment: Do you mean in addition to `xlabel`? Which MATLAB version are you using? If it can be _above_ and not _below_, you can use the `title` command.

Comment: If `title` doesn’t work for you, use `text`, but you’ll have to figure out the coordinates where the text looks good.

Comment: I prefer to use `annotation`.